# woothemes flexslider overwrite prob

Tags: jquery, flexslider, woothemes

I got two problems now

1: When I tried using a proxy site my Slides doesn't work but when I don't use any proxy site, proxyserver my slides seems to work well
Please teach me how to fix this problem

2: [Wootheme flexslider probem](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)

I am now from the carousel part:

![enter image description here][2]

[My website](http://raineerdelarita.comuv.com/test/)

My billboard looks fine when I coded the carousel part my billboard area broke.It overwrites maybe.

![enter image description here][4]

My jquery code:

![enter image description here][5]

When I tried to comment that code nav area, My carousel works but the billboard area not.

![enter image description here][6]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {
    /** $('.flexslider').flexslider(); **/

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5
        });
  });
    </script>
```

html part:

```
<div id="featured">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/slide1.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/slide2.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
        </ul>
  </div> <!-- end flexslider area --> 
    </div> <!-- end container --> 
</div> <!-- end featured area -->
```